# In S3 assign a folder to two user by IAM policy with different access level

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am using Amazon S3 to store client data. There are multiple clients and each client has there own folder in '/Users/' folder with their names. Clients have read and write permission.

To assign permissions to each client dynamically I create a standard policy that I assign at the time of user creation (the policy is below, which working fine).

Now clients have their users also who access that data. But they should have just **read-only** permission on the folder that belongs to their client **Not other folders**.

I created a policy which has read and write access permission:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowUserToSeeBucketListInTheConsole",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowRootAndHomeListingOfCompanyBucket",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "",
                        "Users/",
                        "Users/${aws:username}"
                    ],
                    "s3:delimiter": [
                        "/"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowListingOfUserFolder",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "",
                        "Users/",
                        "Users/${aws:username}/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAllS3ActionsInUserFolder",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/Users/${aws:username}/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Suppose `${aws:username}` is the same folder which belongs to the client.

If I create a second policy with the same as the above just having read-only permission then read-only user's username must be going to different(because username can't be same) so if the second user has the different name then he can't able to access that folder.

Questions:

1. How to create a user and assign a read-only permission to the folder which belongs to its client? (A user with the folder name is already exist with read and write permission)
2. Like `${aws:username}`, is there anything we can assign at time of creating a user and use in the policy like a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I would suggest to avoid using s3:* as much as possible because it can lead to some security issues. For example - in the policy rule below - a combination of `s3:*` together with the condition `s3:prefix` equals `""` seems to me like effectively allowing to manage the whole bucket. And even with a correct limitation to the user folder they may still change the content to public by changing ACL. Which may be fine, but I would rather define it explicitly so you know that this is wanted.

You can also use path `"arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/Users/{username}"` in the bucket ARN and possibly avoid the conditions altogether.

```
        {
        "Sid": "AllowRootAndHomeListingOfCompanyBucket",
        "Action": [
            "s3:*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "s3:prefix": [
                    "",
                    "Users/",
                    "Users/${aws:username}"
                ],
                "s3:delimiter": [
                    "/"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
```

For your question, can you create username and username_ro with their inline policy which you generate with a CloudFormation template where the username will be a parameter. Than you can have an parametrized prescription and also a way how to update the policy for all users consistently. Does it help or am I not getting correctly your issue?

Comment: @peter, Thanks, I will definitely update the policy. As per my knowledge, we can able to create 1500 policies only, and Client and their users are much more. Let me explain again - suppose you create a folder "/Users/petrch" and your user name will be "petrch", policy assign - "bucket-name/Users/{username}/*" with rw access, then you can able to access you folder. To be cont.

Comment: @peter,  now your user want to read the data(User will be just 1) so next user's username will be suppose "petrch_ro" and assign poicy - "bucket-name/Users/{username}/*" with ro access then it can able to access the "/Users/petrch_ro" but we want to read the "/User/petrch/". So how can I create user with ro access to "peter" folder??

Comment: It may be possible with read only users using sts:assumerole from another account, but I it is not very elegant. Otherwise I am afraid that I dont' know.

Comment: assume role is not working, Is it possible to assign a user inline policy?? From user interface(aws website), I don't get any inline policy, It always require first to create a new policy for the user. I don't want to create policy for different user but if there is way through we can assign inline policy at the time of user creation then It can help me a lot.

Comment: Solution - This can be achieved easily by the this approach - Create Read only user with Username - 'petrch_ro' so the policy will have,${aws:username} with read only access, Now full permission user have 'petrch' username and in the policy look like this "${aws:username}_ro". So our both condition satisfies. Thanks :) :)